# listening to keyboard input

Tags: java

I have a Java program that runs in the background without any UI.

Can it listen to keyboard input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800747/event-listener-in-java-without-app-having-focus-global-keypress-detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, unless you use some native magic.