# Java Key Combos

Tags: java, input, key

I want to perform a specific action anytime a certain key combination is pressed while the program is running even if the window is not in focus. For instance, if I press CTRL-U the program would exit. Is this possible?

Comment: This is not supported by Java. Java can only respond to KeyEvents when a window is in focus. You need to use JNI (which I know nothing about) or another language that does allow access to the OS.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901224/listening-for-input-without-focus-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800747/event-listener-in-java-without-app-having-focus-global-keypress-detection

Comment: @camickr, JNA might be easier to deal with, most of the Windows APIs already have C interfaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only real option for this is a lot of JNI. However, this can be quite cumbersome and hard to achieve. My advice is to either go straight C/C++ or not attempt this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the only way it can be done is with JNI.