# How do i Handle keyboard key pressed when my app not focused ( JAVA ) ??

Tags: java, keyboard

How do i Handle keyboard key pressed when my app not focused

so my application can handle any keyboard event while it's in background ??

Comment: You do a search of SO or Google and look for JNI/JNA related questions on the same subject

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event listener in Java without app having focus? (Global keypress detection)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800747/event-listener-in-java-without-app-having-focus-global-keypress-detection)

Comment: @MadProgrammer nice entry point to make search because i didn't know from where to start search :)

Comment: @Nateowami I've search with different key world after no result I've post this question thanks bro :)